# Is there a possibility to override the react admin pagination for the List Component to add an input to let the possibility to choose our page?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-admin

I would like to know if actually react admin does let us override the actual Pagination in the List Component to add an input at the place of the "..." and enter a page number directly instead of clicking on the buttons instead ?

After some investigations I don't think we can actually but maybe i'm wrong I wanted to see if someone did it or it's actually not possible and could be a good feature to add.
[screen to show where i want to override](https://i.stack.imgur.com/scqs5.png)

Answer (score 0):

I would assume you already know React.

If you look at the documentations under [Pagination Component](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/List.html#the-pagination-component), there's actually an example showing you how to create custom pagination.

You can add a custom input as below.

```
const PostPagination = () => {
    const { page, perPage, total, setPage } = useListContext();
    const nbPages = Math.ceil(total / perPage) || 1;
    return (
        nbPages > 1 &&
            <Toolbar>
                {page > 1 &&
                    <Button color="primary" key="prev" onClick={() => setPage(page - 1)}>
                        <ChevronLeft />
                        Prev
                    </Button>
                }
                {page !== nbPages &&
                    <Button color="primary" key="next" onClick={() => setPage(page + 1)}>
                        Next
                        <ChevronRight />
                    </Button>
                }

                {/* add a custom input */}
                <input value={some state} onChange={(e) => setPage(e.target.value)} />


        </Toolbar>
);
```

}

Comment: I already tried this but if we use this example we remove some features actually in the pagination like the rowsPerPageOptions... This example is just to use our pagination but not using the actual one and being more flexible :/

Comment: scroll down a little about extending the Pagination component.

Comment: https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/8c2457af012a24d8764ef6eea1767a4ba1cef80c/packages/ra-ui-materialui/src/list/pagination/PaginationActions.tsx
nothing allow me to do anything else here